# Using jQuery with Angular-CLI Project

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I am using `"@angular/cli": "1.0.2"` and `angular version 4`.

For some reason I had to use jquery based plugin for [select area](https://github.com/360Learning/jquery-select-areas) because I couldn't found equivalent plugin in angular.

This is how my component looks like

```
declare var $ : any;
//adding only necessary code
export class SelectComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private _ngZone: NgZone) {}

    public rowData: any = [];

    ngOnInit() {
        $('img#example').selectAreas({
            minSize: [10, 10],
            onChanged: this.debugQtyAreas,
            width: 500,
            areas: [{
                x: 10,
                y: 20,
                width: 60,
                height: 100,
            }]
        });
    }
    debugQtyAreas(event, id, areas) {
        this.rowData = areas.map(function(obj) {
            return {
                left: obj.x,
                top: obj.y,
                id: obj.id
            };
        });
    };
}
```

Some how this way my jquery thing is working I am able to select areas on a Image.

But the value I am pushing / assigning to array rowData are not updating in the view

I tried searching on internet and found this solution working for everyone but not for me

```
this._ngZone.run(() => {
      //running code inside this 
})
```

But I am getting error here as

> Cannot read property 'run' of undefined

Same thing happening with rowData, when I tried to push data instead of assigning it from map like following

```
for(var i = 0; i < areas.length; i++){
    this.rowData.push({
        left: areas[i].x,
        top: areas[i].y,
        id: obj.id
    });
}
```

> It says Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Comment: Have you imported `NgZone`?

Comment: `import { NgZone } from '@angular/core';` this ? Yes did.

Comment: Show the full code. I believe I know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `bind` when you pass a function by reference if you want to persist the `this` reference.

```
onChanged: this.debugQtyAreas.bind(this)
```

When you're writting inline functions with TypeScript don't use the `function` prefix. If you use the `=>` notation the `this` reference will persist by default.

```
    this.rowData = areas.map((obj) => {
        return {
            left: obj.x,
            top: obj.y,
            id: obj.id
        };
    });
```

Comment: Damn this scope issue. helpful. Thanks.

Comment: can you tell me why my auto-reload stopped working after injecting jquery. Before it was working.

Comment: @Rakeschand try injecting ChangeDetectorRef and calling detectChanges() after you've changed something from a jQuery callback. You might have to also call that method from inside the ngZone.run. I think you had part of the solution. The ngZone.run is misleading as it just lets you run code when the zone is updated.

Comment: Okay Thanks. I'll try.

Answer (score 1):

`this` becomes reserved inside `jQuery` functions and is not referenced to the global scope as it usually is.

I always add this lines at the top of my function:

`let scope = this;`

And then use `scope` instead of this`, e.g.

```
scope._ngZone.run(() => {
  //running code inside this 
})

...

for(var i = 0; i < areas.length; i++){
    scope.rowData.push({
        left: areas[i].x,
        top: areas[i].y,
        id: obj.id
    });
}
```